# How to create "References" section without it being numbered?

Tags: sectioning

I have several sections and at the end of my article if I add `\section{References}` I get it numbered. How to add it without number.

Comment: Try `\section*{References}`

Comment: If it they are at the end of your document, are you looking for `\appendix`? Sections in the appendix are by default still numbered, but with letters instead of numbers.

Comment: @jakun: That's basically 'numbered' anyway.

Comment: Usually, the `\printbibliography` macro does use a `\section*{\refname}` anyway (assuming `biblatex` is being used), so why is there a need of `\section{References}` then?